# Unity : Can't drag GameObject with Text on Script reference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

I'm trying to change the Text of an UI GameObject with a script but Unity doesn't let me drag the GameObject with the text on the script reference and when i do public GameObject it says GameObject is not a Text.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GhostName : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text NameText;
    
    void Start()
    {
        NameText.text = "The Name is : ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your text object must be UI->Text, not text mesh pro for example.

Answer (score 3):

I used TMPro namespace and public TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;
and I was able to drag and drop the Text (TMP) to the script as below:

```
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class className : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    
    public TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;

    void Start()
    {
        scoreText.text = "Score: "+ points;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store `NameText` as a reference to a `GameObject`, and then call `GetComponent<Text>()` to get the Text component on the object. This way, you'll be able to drag the game object into the 'NameText' field in the Unity Inspector window.

```cs
...
public class GhostName : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject NameText;
    
    void Start()
    {
        NameText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "The Name is : ";
    }
}
```

You should also check that `GetComponent<Text>()` is not equal to `null` before setting the value of `.text`.

Comment: Okay the problem wasn't the script. I simply cannot drag objects from the hierarchy into the inspector but thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am totally new to Unity. But it seems I have the same issue.
Under Hierarchy -> right click -> UI, there is only "Text - TextMeshPro" option in my Unity version (2021.3.4f1). I don't know why "Text" is missing. (anyone concur with me?)

So I fail to follow this step in a beginner tutorial, I anyway just select TextMeshPro instead. Then I just cannot drag to script. I guess it is because the tutorial is using Text type not TextMeshPro and they are not compatible.

Later I realize that, to enable the drag action, one cannot use `[SerializeField] Text xxx;` but must use `[SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI xxx;`.
Pls also include `using TMPro;` in the header.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still get this issue, I had to change from "TextMeshPro" to "Text" Object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually on this section right now and i found a fix on that one, older version of unity uses " TextMeshProUGUI " use "TextMeshPro "instead:

```
using System.Collections
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class PlayerUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private TextMeshPro promptText;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
```